# Spring boot SFTP service is failing with the error " Failed to list files; nested exception is 4"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Once in a while our SFTP service fails with below exception. But runs most of the time. On one particular server it fails every alternate days. Here is our code and exception: The code downloads the file, uploads it into S3 bucket and if the operation is successful, moves the old file to archive folder. it is working on most of the servers except in one particular server where it fails on alternate days. If you can think of any reason for alternate day failures, please let me know

```
   return sftpTemplate.invoke(operations -> {
        List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
 //CODE IS FAILING HERE: 
            entries = Arrays.stream(operations.list(sftpProperties.getRemoteDirectory()))
                    .filter(lsEntry -> lsEntry.getFilename().matches(".*\\.csv$"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            if (entries.size() == 0 ){
                LOG.warn( "SFTP of correction file failed to download from SFTP location : Zero files found in SFTP location ");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error( "SFTP of correction file failed to download from SFTP location : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        var wrapper = new Object() {
            Boolean result = false;
        };
        
        for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry lsEntry : entries) {
            String fileName = lsEntry.getFilename();
            
            String remoteFilePath = sftpProperties.getRemoteDirectory() + "/" + lsEntry.getFilename();
            wrapper.result = false;
            String finalFileName = fileName;
            try {
                operations.get(remoteFilePath,
                        stream -> {
                            try {
                                wrapper.result = //upload file to S3 bucket code ....
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                LOG.error( " SFTP of correction file " + finalFileName + " failed to upload to S3 location : " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        });

                if (wrapper.result) {
                    operations.rename(remoteFilePath, sftpProperties.getRemoteDirectory() + "/archive/" + lsEntry.getFilename());
                    LOG.info( " SFTP of correction file " + finalFileName + ": Successfully downloaded and upload to S3 location");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error(AUDIT_MARKER + ": SFTP of correction file " + lsEntry.getFilename() + ": Failed to move to archive folder : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return entries.size();
    });
}
```

Exception is while listing the file. Whenever this exception has happened, the file for sftp was present. Below is the exception:

message

```
 SFTP of correction file failed to download from SFTP location : Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to list files; nested exception is 4:
timestamp   
2023-02-12T22:30:00.001-05:00
```

Comment: Can you get the complete stacktrace of the error?

Comment: These are from AWS logs. and unfortunatelythere is no complete stacktrace. This is what i found from AWS Cloudwatch:  {
    "timestamp": "2023-02-13T23:00:00.044-05:00",
    "transactionId": null,
    "userId": null,
    "level": "INFO",
    "loggerName": "com.jcraft.jsch",
    "message": "Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed",
    "environment": "Local"
}

Comment: Try calling `exists` before `operations.list` to make sure your client also thinks that the directory is there.

Comment: Thank you @tobifasc. it was found that SFTP connection was not getting closed. If previous connection is still hanging, then the next connection request was failing!. The solution was to close the connection!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to close my SFTP connection. If previous connection is not closed properly, and a new connection requests are made, it was failing!.